# How to match a synchronous generator with a powered shaft?

Tags: torque, energy, generator, power-generation

Given is a shaft powered by a steam turbine that rotates unloaded (i.e without generator) at $ \omega $ rad/s and a torque of $T$ Nm. How would one match a generator to extract power requiring a certain torque/rpm such that the shaft does not slow down or better operate at maximum efficiency?

I imagine that when choosing a generator that matches rpm and torque exactly the shaft will not rotate at all.

Assume all relevant parameters are known.

Comment: Why will the shaft become stationary? Or did you mean stationary relative to the generator shaft?

Comment: @SolarMike I would assume that under a certain generator load the shaft will settle at a certain rpm. The shaft without a generator will rotate at an rpm such that driving force (by the steam) matches the friction force in the bearings.

Comment: The Torque $T$ when appied to the generator will rotate the generator at at $ \omega $ rad/s.  The shaft turns.  Very unclear at what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The efficiency of a steam turbine is driven by steam inle tenergy and outlet temp/pressure.  I have never heard of a steam turbine that will run unloaded without overspeeding without speed control.  Clearly, taking power out of the system via a generator will slow the turbine down.  Generally, this is covered by a governor which introduces more steam when it does.

Your "given" condition isn't realistic unless you found a turbine running out in the wild, which seems unlikely.  Generators are matched to turbines based on the turbine nameplate data and the steam available to it.